# How to access and read JVMs class file members?

Tags: java, class, file, jvm

I'm not very familiar with JVM and I have an assignment involving the Class file.

*Write a java program that when run as*

```
java DissectClassFile file1.class file2.class ...
```

*it will print a summary of each class file as follows:

the name of the class defined by the class file,

its super class and interfaces it implements,

the number of items in the constant pool,

the number of interfaces implemented by the class, and their names,

the number of fields of the class whose name contain the underscore character,

the number of methods of the class whose names contain at least one capital letter*

Right off the bat I don't know where to begin.  If someone could help me out and point me in the correct direction, I should get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html). It contains an explanation of the [class file format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a class java.lang.Class to access that information. For every Class, you can call MyClass.class (for example, String.class) to get the object with the information for that class.

Comment: I know how to do that, like
`Class c = MyClass.getClass();`
But how do you convert the string argument coming into main which would be "MyClass.class" to be able to set it equal to a Class.

Comment: @Gus: If you want to use Reflection, use `Class.forName(...)`. Of course, this only works for classes actually on the class path. And your task looks like you should parse the class file yourself, as some of the information there is not available with reflection.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann:  I am not very experienced with reflection, but your comment surprises me.  What parts of the stated task can reflection not achieve?  BTW - would it not be possible to add classes to the run-time class-path using an `URLClassLoader`?

Comment: @Andrew: It is in fact only one: *the number of items in the constant pool*. This is an implementation detail, and not available through reflection. – You are right about an URLClassLoader, of course. (`Class.forName` takes an optional ClassLoader argument.)

Comment: @Paŭlo:  Thanks for clarifying.  Given it will do 'all but one' of the stated aims, I'm going to give both replies an up vote. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of this information can easily be gleaned loading each class using `Class.forName(...)` and using the reflection APIs to fish out the information.  **However** the constant pool size is the killer.  AFAIK, this can only be determined from the class file itself.

So, your options would seem to be:

- Write a bunch of code to read and decode class files.  The JVM spec has the details of the [class file format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html).
- Use an existing library such as [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) to take care of the low-level class file parsing.
- Use a hybrid of class file parsing (using either of the above) to extract the constant pool size, and the reflection APIs for the rest.

I imagine that your assignment hints at which way they expect you to go.  But if not, I'd look at the BCEL approach first.

Comment: I believe the assignment wants me to write all the code to read and decode class files.  I have no idea where to start from there if I'm not using the reflection API.  I've been reading the JVM spec but I have no idea on how to implement it.  Could you show me a little example?

Comment: @Gus - what don't you understand?  Reading a binary file?  To decode it, you need to read and understand the spec for the class file format (linked) ... then its simply a matter doing binary reads, etc.